# Google maps + javascript only rendering correctly when alerts are coded in

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

I'm using this example:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/icon-complex

to render a multi-marker google map based on a array variable of data.

Here's my code:

```
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

var locations = [
    ["Title1", "Ballyblack Road, Portaferry, United Kingdom", 0, "/images/pins/1.png"],
    ["Title2", "Coach Road, Portaferry, United Kingdom", 1, "/images/pins/2.png"],
    ["Title3", "Cook Street, Portaferry, United Kingdom", 2, "/images/pins/2.png"],
    ["Title4", "Ballyfounder Road, Portaferry, United Kingdom", 3, "/images/pins/1.png"],
    ["Title5", "Shore Road, Strangford, United Kingdom", 4, "/images/pins/3.png"],
    ["Title6", "Cook Street, Portaferry, United Kingdom", 5, "/images/pins/1.png"],
    ["Title7", "Windmill Hill, Portaferry, United Kingdom", 6, "/images/pins/4.png"],
    ["Title8", "BT32", 7, "/images/pins/TownlandsandGateways.png"],
    ["Title9", "Shore Road, Strangford, United Kingdom", 8, "/images/pins/4.png"],
    ["Title10", "Windmill Lane, Portaferry, United Kingdom", 9, "/images/pins/1.png"],
    ["Title11", "The Saltpans, Portaferry, United Kingdom", 10, "/images/pins/3.png"],
    ["Title12", "Cuan View, Portaferry, United Kingdom", 11, "/images/pins/4.png"],
    ["Title13", "Lough Shore Road, Portaferry, United Kingdom", 12, "/images/pins/3.png"],
    ["Title14", "Castleward Road, Down, United Kingdom", 13, "/images/pins/1.png"],
    ["Title15", "Bar Hall Road, Portaferry, United Kingdom", 14, "/images/pins/2.png"],
    ["Title16", "Bar Hall Road, Portaferry, United Kingdom", 15, "/images/pins/1.png"]
];

function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {center: new google.maps.LatLng(54.380357, -5.542774), zoom: 14};
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
    setMarkers(map, locations);
}

function setMarkers(map, locations) {
    for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {

        var location = locations[i];

        geocoder.geocode({'address': location[1]}, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                markers = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: results[0].geometry.location,
                    map: map,
                    icon: location[3],
                    title: location[0],
                    zIndex: location[2]
                });
            }
        });
// alert(location[1]);
    }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

The array params are ["Title", "Location", "zIndex", "Image"]

You'll see that I've commented out the alert close to the bottom. When I run this code it renders  all 16 pins, but they are all pin 16 - although it does find the correct location for them, the marker images are all the same and the titles are all the same.

When I uncomment the alert, and click the "Ok" on the alert box, the markers all render correctly, with their own titles and their own icons.

I'm scratching my head, wondering how the correct location was found for each but not the right title or icon image...!

My guess is that the code is running to quickly for the map to find the right values... but my intuition is saying... REALLY??? TOO QUICKLY???

I'm am eventually planning on building the array from a large database so there will be maybe 100's of markers.

Any advice on what I might be doing wrong?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because you don't wait for the **geocoder** response, changing the variable **location** before the geocode returns its response.
You should have something like this:

```
function setMarkers(map, locations) {
    for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {

        setMarker( map, locations[i] );

    }
}


function setMarker( map, location ) {
    geocoder.geocode({'address': location[1]}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            markers = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: results[0].geometry.location,
                map: map,
                icon: location[3],
                title: location[0],
                zIndex: location[2]
            });
        }
    });
}
```

In this way you gonna have a different local variable **location** for each marker.